# Do modern C++ compilers optimize away repeated accesses to the same data member of a class?

Tags: c++, optimization, compilation

Consider:

```
class A
{
public:
    const int& my_int_member() const { return my_int_member; }
    const double& my_double_member const {return my_double_member; }
private:
    int my_int_member;
    double my_double_member;
};

class B
{
public:
    const A& my_A_member() const { return my_A_member; }
private:
    A my_A_member;
};
```

Do modern c++ compilers (e.g. msvc, clang, gcc), set with the maximum optimization level each one provides, usually recognize and optimize away repeated accesses to the same data member as in:

```
B b;
do_stuff(b.my_A_member().my_double_member(), b.my_A_member().my_int_member());
double c = b.my_A_member().my_double_member() + b.my_A_member().my_int_member();
```

That is, do they realize that they can reuse the same reference or do they just do the access again?

Comment: you can try and see here: https://godbolt.org/ . I would be surprised if not

Comment: actually I would expect a decent compiler to create something equivalent to `double c = 0;` for the last line

Comment: Maybe.  It is impossible to give a general answer. It depends on how the compiler/optimiser is implemented - how aggressively it looks for opportunities to remove repeated accesses, and what it does if it finds an opportunity. Compiler vendors COMPETE by doing things - including optimisation - differently, each doing things that suit some set of users (developers) better than their competitors. But no compiler is (yet) perfect for everything. The only way to be sure is, for your chosen compiler(s) and optimisation settings, to check the compiler's output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If definition is visible, and if compiler can prove that it does the same things (optimization with the as-if rule) (which is more tricky that we can thing, with aliases, global accesses, ...), it can do it (and probably does it).

But imagine that we modify a little your example to (b is no longer local, but given as parameter):

```
void foo(B& b)
{
    do_stuff(b.my_A_member().my_double_member(), b.my_A_member().my_int_member());
    double c = b.my_A_member().my_double_member() + b.my_A_member().my_int_member();
}
```

Can `do_stuff` modify a global `B` which would be the parameter of `foo`.
Without definition, the answer is yes.
So compiler has to reload `b.my_A_member()` after the call to `do_stuff`

For readability, I would anyway do:

```
B b;
const auto& a = b.my_A_member();
do_stuff(a.my_double_member(), a.my_int_member());
double c = a.my_double_member() + a.my_int_member();
```